# Ant can't find build.xml

Tags: python, ant

I am trying to convert a Python script to use in Android environment. Am not a Java programmer, but hoping to scratch my way through this.

Here is output I'm seeing. Get an error referring to Android 8 but not sure if relevant.

I see build.xml in pgs4a/buildlib...

```
jake@jake-purple ~/Python/pgs4a-0.9.4 $ ./android.py build /home/jake/Python/Darts/touchtest release

Updating build files.

Error: Target id 'android-8' is not valid. Use 'android list targets' to get the target ids.

Creating assets directory.


Packaging internal data.

Listing private ...
Listing private/lib ...
Listing private/lib/PIL ...
Listing private/lib/android ...
Compiling private/lib/android/__init__.py ...
Compiling private/lib/android/apk.py ...
Compiling private/lib/android/mixer.py ...
Listing private/lib/encodings ...
Listing private/lib/json ...
Listing private/lib/pygame ...
Listing private/lib/pygame/threads ...
Listing private/lib/sqlite3 ...
Listing engine-private ...

Packaging external data.

Listing /home/jake/Python/Darts/touchtest ...
Compiling /home/jake/Python/Darts/touchtest/touchtest_2.py ...

I'm using Ant to build the package.

Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed

The build seems to have failed.
```

Comment: so assume I have a path problem...

Comment: The above error is shown when ant command is run and build.xml file does not exists.